# Dont show URL in address bar

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on a PHP project.

When I click on index page then it shows : `www.abc.com/index.html`
When I click on xyz page then it shows : `www.abc.com/xyz.html`

But I dont want to show like that.

I want to show like :
When I will click on index page then : `www.abc.com`
When I click on xyz page then it shows : `www.abc.com/xyz`

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google `"URL re-writing"`

Comment: You could try to have a look at some MV* frameworks like angular, ember etc. or you could develop it with NodeJs too  with express js . Another suggestion is to have a framework bundle like wordpress, joomla, codeigniter, cakephp etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `ReWrite` in `.htaccess`. If you don't know what `.htaccess`-file is, I suggest you Google it.

Your problem can be solved with something like this in a `.htaccess`-file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```